# Wrapper Classes, Difference in functionality when creating object via a String parameter in Constructor?

Tags: java, string, integer, wrapper

In terms of instances of wrapper classes, does the instance behave differently when the instance is created via a `String` arg in the constructor in comparison to an `int`, `double` etc.

E.g is there a difference in:

```
Integer wrapperInt= new Integer(33);

Integer wrapperInt2= new Integer("33");
```

Comment: Why should it? What functionality do you expect to differ exactly?

Comment: What's the difference you are expecting?

Comment: Can't you check the JDK source?

Comment: What do u mean by JDK source?

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html (for example)

Comment: @RNI2013 The source code of the class `Integer` that you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Answer (score 4):

The end result will be the same - you'll have an `Integer` object with the value `33`.

The version that takes a `String` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input string cannot be parsed.

Note: There's no need to write a statement like `Integer wrapperInt = new Integer(33);`. Let the compiler do it for you (auto-boxing):

```
Integer wrapperInt = 33;
```

If, for some reason, you do not want to use auto-boxing, then at least use `Integer.valueOf(...)` instead of using the constructor:

```
Integer wrapperInt = Integer.valueOf(33);
```

This is more efficient; the `valueOf` method can return a cached object (so that it's not necessary to create a new `Integer` object).

Comment: Correct for 33 but incorrect in the general case; there's an edge case involving octal.

Comment: What do you mean "an edge case involving octal"? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. Both instances represent the integer 33. If there was a difference, it would be written in the javadoc.

Note that you should favor the usage of the factory methods instead:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(33);
i = Integer.valueOf("33");
```

Comment: Read the question. The question is not "do these constructors do the same thing". Obviously they don't, since one takes an int and the other one a String. The question is: "do instances behave differently"? And the answer is no: an Integer, whether it's created with one or the other constructor, behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is you will be creating a string object unnecessarily in the second approach and it will try to parse the string you have passed to the constructor, If it couldn't parse the string then it will throw NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that **yes, there can be a difference between the two syntaxes**. Specifically, the syntax

```
new Integer(33);
```

results in the value 33 being interpreted as an integer constant by the compiler and stored as a literal in the code. By contrast, the syntax

```
new Integer("33");
```

results in a call that routes the string value through `Integer.parseInt(s, 10)`. This matters if the value in question has a leading zero character; in the case of an `int` literal, the compiler will evaluate the literal as octal:

```
new Integer(010); // equals 8
```

By contrast, the string constructor will always evaluate the value as base 10:

```
new Integer("010"); // equals 10
```

In any case, you should almost always be using `Integer.valueOf()`, as it is usually more efficient.